# Printing a shape from numbers in python

Tags: python, computer-science

I'm trying to create a function called `shape` with loops that prints a shape of `n` rows and `n*2` columns.

For example:

`shape(5)` prints the following:

[image]

I have tried to do many things but haven't been successful yet. The following code was what I could come up with so far.

```
def shape(n):
    tri = ""
    for i in range (1, n+1):
        tri = tri + (str(i))
        print(tri)
        i += 1
```

which produces:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here are some hints. First focus on getting your numbers right with what you have. Then separate the result you want into two halfs, the first half and second half. Once your numbers are correct add the `.` to the first half. Then for the second half is simply the reverse of what you did for the first half.

Comment: I'd also note that I'd highly recommend trying to try solving this yourself as much as possible before copy and pasting one of the code-only answers below. You may get the right answer but provides no benefit as a student and problem solver, it's a waste of a good learning opportunity to improve yourself as a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def shape(n): 
    st = ""
    nums = ""
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        nums = nums + str(i)
        st = nums + "." * (2*(i-1)) + nums[::-1]
        print (st)
```

Result:

```
5........5
54......45
543....345
5432..2345
5432112345
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def shape(n):
    for r in range(n):
        s = ''
        for i in range(n):
            s += str(n - i) if i <= r else '.'
        print(s, s[::-1], sep='')
```

or:

```
def shape(n):
    s = ''
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        s += str(i)
        print(s + '.' * (i - 1) * 2 + s[::-1])
```

or, without using a reversing slice:

```
def shape(n):
    s = r = ''
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        s += str(i)
        r = str(i) + r
        print(s + '.' * (i - 1) * 2 + r)
```

so that:

```
shape(5)
```

outputs:

```
5........5
54......45
543....345
5432..2345
5432112345
```

Comment: is there also a way of doing this without actually reversing a string or using any type of reverse function for that purpose?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that uses no reversing slice then.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be the following:

```
def shape(n):
    prefix = ''
    total = (2 * n)
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        prefix += str(i)
        suffix = ''.join(reversed(prefix))
        dots = '.' * (total - (len(prefix) + len(suffix)))
        print(prefix + dots + suffix)

shape(5)
```

**Output**

```
5........5
54......45
543....345
5432..2345
5432112345
```

Answer (score 0):

Using conventional for loop to print. Though it can be done using other methods as everyone else did.

```
rows = int(input())

for i in range(0,rows,1):
    for j in range(rows,rows-i-1,-1):
        print(j,end="")
    for j in range(0,2*((rows-i)-1),1):
        print(".",end="")
    for j in range(rows-i,rows+1,1):
        print(j,end="")
    print()
```

Input = 5, Output :

```
5........5
54......45
543....345
5432..2345
5432112345
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def shape(n):
    n= 5
    tri = ['.'] * (2*n)  
    for i in range(0,n):
        tri[i]=str(n-i)
        tri[2*n-i-1]=str(n-i)
        print(*tri, sep='')

5........5
54......45
543....345
5432..2345
5432112345
```